# auto.arima results in R has no intercept

Tags: r, time-series, arima, interpretation, intercept

After fitting an ARIMA model with a covariate using the `auto.arima` function in R, I get the following results
[image]

What could be the reason as to why my results do not include the intercept. Also, I would highly appreciate interpreting the important metrics from the summary above.

Comment: The automatic model search routine believes that no mean is needed. Unfortunately, just how this happens is not described on the help page, so you would need to hunt through the [source code](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecast/index.html) if you are really interested. Re your second question: I would recommend posting a new question on that (because it is really different from "why no intercept?"), ideally [posting the output as text (formatted as code) rather than as a picture](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3176/).

Comment: See https://otexts.com/fpp2/arima-r.html#how-does-auto.arima-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `auto.arima()` has many arguments that you can add. Maybe what you are looking for `auto.arima(x, allowmean = TRUE)`, because I am not sure that the default settings allows mean to be modeled. Also, as @Stephan-Kolassa said, apparently no mean is needed.